# Not able to select fields inside struct in pyspark dataframe with Spark version 3.3.0

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running a dataproc pyspark job on gcp to read data from hudi table (parquet format) into pyspark dataframe. Below is the output of `printSchema()` on pyspark dataframe.

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- p: integer (nullable = true)
```

With dataproc version 2.0 (spark 3.1.3), I am able to select any column from dataframe as in the code below.

```
df = df.select(
        col("id"),
        col("data.name")
       )
```

However, after migrating to dataproc version 2.1 (spark 3.3.0), I am not able to select struct type columns and their fields (ex: `data.name`), it gives below error. Though other string type columns works fine (ex: `id`).

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 516): java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch (org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow and org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Can someone help? Am I missing any spark configuration setting?

Comment: Which version of pyspark and python you are using? You can refer to this [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/#:~:text=Spark%20runs%20on%20Java%208,3.6%2B%20and%20R%203.5%2B.) for compatible versions and this [link](https://medium.com/sicara/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f).

Comment: thanks for your response! I am using pyspark 3.3.0 and python 3.10

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.